# Is there a built in class I can use to parse a string containing a MySQL column datatype and return an equivalent .NET Type object?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0, odbc

Is there a built in class I can use to parse a string containing a MySQL column datatype and return an equivalent .NET Type object?

I want to convert some code that reads the column information from a table so that instead of having to pull back a row of data and getting the Schema information from that (using OdbcDataAdapter.FillSchema) - instead the method issues a command that does not do a table scan (hopefully quicker) to get the same info.

Existing code to be replaced:

```
        QueryStr.Append("SELECT * FROM ")
                .Append("`" + tableName + "`")
                .Append(" LIMIT 1 ");

        DataTable dsTable = new DataTable();

        using (OdbcConnection DbConn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionStr))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter cmd = new OdbcDataAdapter(QueryStr.ToString(), DbConn);

            try
            {
                cmd.FillSchema(dsTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
                QuerySuccessful = true;
            }
```

Attempt at new code:

```
        StringBuilder QueryStr = new StringBuilder();
        QueryStr.Append("DESCRIBE ")
                .Append("`" + tableName + "`");

        DataTable dsTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection DbConn = new OdbcConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                DbConn.Open();

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(QueryStr.ToString(), DbConn);


                OdbcDataReader odrColumnReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (odrColumnReader.Read())
                {
                    string strColumnName = odrColumnReader.GetString(0);
                    string strColumnType = odrColumnReader.GetString(1);

                    // strColumnType is a string containing the type - e.g. char(6) or whatever

                    Type type = typeof (string); // TODO replace this bit with  a conversion of strColumnType                        

                    columns.Add( new SQLcolumn(strColumnName, type, tableName));


                }

                DbConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

The trouble with this is that I get back strColumnType as a string - I want to convert it to a .NET type to match what I got back from FillSchema.

I'd prefer not to code my own conversion method [using this info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668763.aspx ] if one exists in the FrameWork / ODBC / ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OdbcDataReader.GetFieldType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getfieldtype.aspx), eg:

```
Type firstColumnType = odrColumnReader.GetFieldType(0);
```

Comment: Just tried this: it told me about the 'DESCRIBE' results table - rather than the table I am running DESCRIBE on.
i.e. DESCRIBE gives you a results table of columns "Field" "Type" "Null" "Key" "Default" "Extra" - and this command reported on the types of those 5 columns.
It looks to me like it would work if I got a row of data back - but that is what I'd like to move away from.

Comment: Ah I see, having just had a look at the inner workings of the GetFieldType method, it uses the internal sealed classes System.Data.Odbc.DbSchemaInfo and System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap class to figure this information out. You could hook into the relevent methods via reflection, but this is obviously not nice. I'd recommend creating a static `Dictionary<string, Type>` with the relevant information in.